# RequestAdditionalTime not working after upgrading to ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Windows Service self-hosted application, when it is starting, it has to pre-load data and this could take 60 seconds.  So the app call `RequestAdditionalTime` on startup to avoid timeout error.

This works fine before.
Recently we upgraded to ASP.NET Core 2.0, self-hosted in Windows Service, the approach is described in Microsoft doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/windows-service). `TargetFramework` is set to `net472`

Within the derived class of `WebHostService`, `RequestAdditionalTime` is called as below.

```
public class CustomWebHostService : WebHostService
{
    public CustomWebHostService(IWebHost host) : base(host)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnStarting(string[] args)
    {
        this.RequestAdditionalTime(1000 * 60 * 5);
        base.OnStarting(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStarted()
    {
        this.RequestAdditionalTime(1000 * 60 * 5);
        base.OnStarted();
    }
}
```

But it does not work.

> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
>   A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the XXXX service to connect.

Now I fixed this issue by editing the registry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control]
"ServicesPipeTimeout"=dword:0002bf20
```

Does anyone know why `RequestAdditionalTime` does not work any more?

Comment: which version of .net core?

Comment: ASP.NET Core 2.0 running on .NET framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requesting 5 minutes, but the hard maximum is 2 minutes. any values greater than two minutes will be ignored and the limit stays at what is configured in the registry.